# Реализовать бонусную систему в интернет-магазине

Tags: mysql

Необходимо реализовать бонусную систему для зарегистрированных пользователей, т.е. у каждого пользователя есть специальный бонусный счет, с каждой покупки ему начисляется **N%** в виде бонусов, далее он может оплачивать до **M%** от стоимости покупки этими бонусами.

**Вопрос**: в каком виде реализовать такой бонусный счёт?

Я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Просто создать отдельное поле `bonus` в таблице `users`, и соответственно прибавлять\вычитать бонусы из этого поля.
2. Создать отдельную таблицу **"История начисления бонусов"**, в которой хранить отдельными записями поступление и вычитание бонусов.

1-й вариант я сразу отметаю, а вот по второму есть вопросы:

- Как определять актуальный баланс бонусного счета?
- Каким образом построить структуру таблицы, чтобы в будущем даже при очень большом количестве записей быстро определять текущий баланс любого пользователя?
- Может нужно периодически очищать старые записи из этой таблицы?
- Или может скомбинировать 2 этих способа? Т.е. периодически из таблицы **"История начисления бонусов"** вычислять текущий баланс и записывать его в отдельное поле таблицы `users`.

Как я себе представляю набор полей такой таблицы:

- **id**
- **date** (дата списания\начисления)
- **user_id** (id пользователя)
- **summa** (сумма списания, если положительная, то это начисление, если отрицательная, то списание).

Возможно нужны ещё какие-то служебные поля или вместо **summa** лучше сделать отдельные поля для зачисления и списания?

В общем буду рад любому совету или помощи! ;)

Comment: по идее живой человек не может сделать столько покупок, чтобы подсчет баланса (сумма максимум пары сотен чисел) занимал хоть какое-то измеримое время. В любом случае проблему кэширования можно отложить на потом.

Comment: @Ипатьев, я имею ввиду что в одной таблице будут записи всех пользователей, и записей может быть достаточно много. Но, собственно основной вопрос в том, как правильно реализовать такую таблицу, какие должны быть поля и как потом из этих записей получать актуальный баланс

Comment: Чтобы посчитать сумму полученых и потраченых бонусов, нужна одна колонка. Можете потренироваться в экселе, если в БД не получается посчитать сумму в колонке чисел. Чтобы посчитать баланс одного пользователя, вам не нужны все записи в таблице. Вам нужны только записи этого пользователя. А их по определению не будет "очень много"

Comment: А чем первый вариант не устраивает? Зачем Вам каждый раз пересчитывать, сколько у пользователя бонусов? Просто начисляйте и вычитайте. А там уже ведите логи с историей движения — если будут какие-то спорные ситуации, к ним можно обращаться. Но просто так систему напрягать для пересчета нет смысла никакого.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, боюсь, что если в какой-то момент произойдет ошибочное списание или начисление, потом конца и края не найдешь, и одна ошибка может сбросить баланс или ещё что по хуже. Может я и не прав, поэтому и задаю вопрос на форуме, может найдется человек, у которого был реальный опыт разработки такой системы )

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев Так для этого и вести логи. Просто сама система вряд ли баг такой допустит, если Вы правильно настроите конкурентные запросы и самостоятельно ошибок не наделаете. Сколько уже ни делал одним полем, ошибок из разряда "оно само что-то сломалось" не возникало. Опять же, Вы вряд ли пишете свой алиэкспресс с 100500 покупками в секунду, не нужно так париться)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar "первый вариант с логами" это на самом деле второй вариант с денормализацией, который предложил сам автор в своем вопросе. Только у него эти две сущности все-таки связаны, а у вас они вообще никак не пересекаются. Но если "по логам" нельзя получить ту же цифру, что и в "одном поле" то их можно выкидывать на помойку - они нужны как рыбке зонтик.

Comment: @Ипатьев По большому счету у него частный случай логов. Они и не должны пересекаться. Но по логам можно восстановить цифру, если это понадобится. Только делать этого автоматически по времени не надо, в холостую нагружать машину ради пересчета того же числа

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев в общем не надо слушать все эти россказни, "я сто раз делал, ничего не ломалось". Когда сломается, эти мантры не помогут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2й вариант предпочтительнее

Табличку лучше расширить согласно бизнес логике:

- `id`
- `date` (дата списания\начисления)
- `user_id` (id пользователя)
- `summa` бонуса
- `type_`  (начисление бонуса, оплата бонусом, списание бонуса ......, ручное зачисление)
  `id_order` (к какому заказу принадлежит ордер)

Вероятно, можно ее расширить, если к примеру есть валюты.

Текущий баланс бонуса = сумм(summa) where user_id == curentUser->ID

В нужных местах, связанных с оплатой на сайте и возврата заказа (случаи бывают разные) в админке вставить функции, связанные с инсертом строчек по пользователю.